# How does this normal map create surface imperfections instead of elevations/bumps?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, normals, normal-map, pbr

How do you create a normal map similar to this?

[image]

[image]

In this polyester texture I just purchased, I noticed that the normal map (instead of roughness) is creating the silky look as well as the surface imperfections. This normal map looks flat and has patches of different colors Instead of bumps/elevations. How can I re-create this effect without using a texturing software?

I know how to make different PBR maps in Photoshop using only a diffuse map, but I'm not able to re-create a normal map similar to the image above. No matter what pattern (scratches, smudges, etc.) I use to try and make a normal map from, it ends up creating bumps/elevations instead of surface imperfections. 
**How do you achieve this "silky" look along with surface imperfections using a normal map? How can I use a diffuse map of different patterns to create a normal map like this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

That was probably a Voronoi procedural texture generator plugged in as the normal map of the texture. Here's a satiny example from Blender's noise texture (Shader Editor, Shift-A | Texture | Noise Texture).

Answer (score 0):

You can bake textures like this in Blender. After setting up all the components of the shader you want to bake in the Shader Editor:

1 - Create a new image in the UV Editor

2 - Add an Image Texture in your Shader Editor and select the image you created in step 1 as the image being referenced

3, 4, 5 -  In your Render Properties tab, select Cycles, select your Bake Type (Normal in your case), and hit the Bake button

6 - A normal map will be generated consolidating all normal elements present in your shader as the image in your UV Editor

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm familiar with baking in blender. My question is how to create such effect/textures to begin with. I know I can create imperfections by creating a mask and using it for the roughness value, but how can I create a silky texture using the normal map? When I use any image to generate a normal map from it always uses the imperfections (different color values on the image) to create bumps or holes. How can I create a normal map similar to the one in my post, which affects shininess and imperfections, instead of height variations?

Comment: Also, It would help a lot if you share the texture you used for the normal map on the cube (not the baked texture, but the original one plugged into the normal map), and if you can describe how you generated that. I'm guessing it's a Voronoi texture? but not sure your exact setup.